# Need help to understand the code

Tags: numerics, programming, integral-transforms

Here is the code by P. Valko and J. Abate for finding numerical inverse Laplace transform by trapezoidal's rule. Can someone willing to explain this code? I don't understand this part: `Plus @@ Append`

```
talbot[F_, t_, M_: 32] :=
     Module[{np, r, S, theta, sigma},
      np = Max[M, $MachinePrecision];
      r = SetPrecision[2 M/(5 t), np];
      S = r theta (Cot[theta] + I);
      sigma = theta + (theta Cot[theta] - 1) Cot[theta];
      (r/M) Plus @@ Append[Table[Re[Exp[t S] (1 + I sigma) F[S]],
                  {theta, Pi/M, (M - 1) Pi/M, Pi/M}],
                     (1/2) Exp[r t] F[r]]]
fun[s_] = 1/(s - 1); %example use
t0 = 1;
ft = talbot[fun, t0]
```

Comment: Next time, please provide [a link](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/ID/5026/) to wherever you obtained code you did not write yourself.

Comment: @J.M. but it's from a paper. How to link? I forgot where i got the paper.

Comment: Then you try to find a link to that paper. The point is to make it easy for other people to refer to a reference when needed.

Comment: In any event, an expression like `Plus @@ Append[list, c]` would now be written as `Total[Append[list, c]]`, tho things might be clearer if it's written as `c + Total[list]`. Note that you can always highlight symbols like `@@` in the front end and press F1 to see the relevant docs.